# AWS can't figure out how to pass iot button serial number to a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working with a lambda function that will be speaking to dynamodb and have a devices serial number already in the database. I need to pass the device's serial number that triggered the lambda function so I can query database info about each device.

Comment: I am working in python for my lambda function

Answer (score -1):

event.get('serialNumber') if using python